# Apache configuration and mysql max_used_connection conflict on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, mysql5.1

I have some serious problems with my production server running Ubuntu 11.10 with 48GB RAM.
The setup of my webserver (Apache 2.1) is configured to use approximately 18 GB of RAM. I tried to calculate this value by setting

- **max_clients 800**

with each child process taking nearly 23MB ram

- **max_spare_servers 200**
- **keepAlive on**
- **keepalivetimeout 3**

Apache MPM is set to **prefork module**

Additionally we are using

- **php 5.3.2**
- **PDO to connect to database**

I made similar changes to my MySQL server (v5.1) by changing **max_used_connections to 800** with

- **key_buffer** to 4Gb (Myisam as default engine with 3 tables of innodb)
- **key_buffer_size** + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size ) * max_connections = 5.4Gb

Now **max_used_connection** is increasing rapidly and after a couple of hours it stopped at **595** and again it climbed to its max value of 800. I even tried changing to default mysql configuration but still no change.

For some reason changing to Apache's default configuration solves the problem now **max_used_connections** is steady at around **57**.

Does anyone have an idea about this behavior? 
Can Apaches configuration impact Mysql performance?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You talk about serious problems which are...? Does your server crash, quit services? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible way to run apache on a large server.

Please consider running the worker MPM (lightweight threading model), and proxy dynamic requests (PHP) to a fastCGI backend via the official apache mod_fcgid module.

Also make SURE you set a static number of PHP -> mysqli connections, and re-use this pool.

You could trivially support 5000 concurrent clients with the above setup.

Comment: To switch to the worker MPM like suggest by adaptr, ensure all your PHP modules are thread safe, or you run into other problems.

Comment: I specifically advised him to run PHP on fastCGI. That does not have threading issues, since every connection is single-threaded.

Comment: You are right, i skipped reading. My bad